# Struts 2 : investigate request origin

Tags: struts2, interceptor

Our Payroll application needs to be extended with a function that tracks when enter and leave work during the day. We are deploying a JSP page on several terminals around our country.

The JSP page that provides this capability, is part of a big struts2 application. 
What we want, is to check the origin of the request, when  the JSP page calls an action form one of out terminals. We need to check the IP, match the relative DNS name, and so on.... but this is not the matter!

The matter is: *How should we do this ?*

I am thinking about to develop an Interceptors that will be attached to all the actions that requires request origin validation. 
Do you think this is a good approach?

Does already exists an interceptor that provide this functionality?

Comment: I'd suggest you to try your solution first and then come back later here if it doesn't work as expected or if you experiment problems.

Comment: You talk of "JSP page that provides this capability", a "JSP that calls an action", etc. That's misleading. A JSP page (in Struts2 and most modern frameworks) is the last element of the request cycle, which just shows the result of the action.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to check the dns, but if you want to check the origin of the request, which i presume to be client's ip address, you can get it by httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr(). don't forget to make your action implements ServletRequestAware